# Laravel - Using Stream with the new Http client

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm migrating my old system to the new version of Laravel, and I'm having problems with one of my requests...

Basically on this request I receive any file and simply forward it to the user. Here is the old version using `Guzzle`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

public function getMedia($media)
{
    try {
        $response = $this->client->get('media/' . $media, [
                'stream' => true
            ]
        );

        $contentType = $response->getHeader('Content-Type');

        $body = $response->getBody();

        $stream = new StreamedResponse(function () use ($body) {
            while (!$body->eof()) {
                echo $body->read(1024);
            }
        });

        $stream->headers->set('Content-Type', $contentType);

        return $stream;
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'errors' => json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents())->errors,
            'message' => 'Unfortunately we could not find the requested file'
        ], 404);
    }
}
```

And the new code that I tried to write, without success:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

public function getMedia($media)
{
    $response = Http::withOptions([
        'stream' => true
    ])->get("media/{$media}");

    $contentType = $response->header('Content-Type');

    $body = $response->body();

    $stream = new StreamedResponse(function () use ($body) {
        while (!$body->eof()) {
            echo $body->read(1024);
        }
    });

    $stream->headers->set('Content-Type', $contentType);

    return $stream;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? I don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: What does without success mean? Can you give more details about where it's failing on you? Right away - `media/{$media}` looks like a typo (brackets)

Comment: @Bryan The Http client from Laravel 7 don't recognize `eof()` and `read()` method, or I'm just doing something dumb...

Comment: Looks like body is a string: https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Http/Client/Response.html#method_body probably better off using guzzle if you want a stream.

Comment: If there is just something like try catch block in PHP...

Answer (score 4):

I know, 2 years late, but i'm doing something similar, you should access to the response via the psr

instead of:

```php
$body = $response->body(); // This try to return an string
```

Use this:

```php
$body = $response->toPsrResponse()->getBody(); // the guzzle response
```

Then you can use your normal code

I hope someone can find this useful,

Comment: Interesting, will try it latter